# How can I zoom out the Timeline Panel in Eclipse SDK?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-traceview

How can I zoom out the [Timeline Panel](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html#timelinepanel) when viewing a trace file in Eclipse SDK?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> To zoom in: there are only need to hold your mouse and drag over
>   **graph's displays**.
>
> To zoom out: hold your mouse and drag over **time ruler** at the top.
>
> To zoom all the way out: **double click** on the **time ruler** at the top

Comment: To zoom all the way out: double click on the time ruler at the top.

Comment: The "time ruler" is the thing on the top of the trace-window that sais `msec: XXX` on the left and and on the right `max: msec: XXX (real time, dual clock)`. Took me way too long to find it.